# How can I set some items of listview , so that they can NOT be selected

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview, and there are items in it,

but there are some items that I dont want to be selected,

is there any way that I can put those items in listview but can not be selected?

Comment: did you try setting the disabled property for the particular list item .

Comment: Which technology (WinForms, ASP.Net, Windows Runtime, etc.)?

Comment: there is no option named **disabled** or **enable**

Comment: @chuex I am using WinForms